# Convert Datatables array value from Integer to String

Tags: php, datatable

My database has a column called `status` which store only integer `0,1,2..`. Currently im listing all my database data to a datatable but how can i display my `status` column as string instead of the integer `0,1,2` ? I'm displaying the int value straight from database to table (which are 0,1,2), but i want to process the (0,1,2) and display (0 =`Pending`, 1 = `Running` , 2 = `Completed`.)

My database column :
[Column Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrslH.png)

Image: [Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2avT.png)

Expected result : [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYPWT.png)

PHP:

```
// DB table to use 
$table = 'projects';

// Table's primary key 
$primaryKey = 'projectID';


// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. 
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database.  
// The `dt` parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. 
$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'projectName', 'dt' => 0),
    array('db' => 'projectDescription',  'dt' => 1),
    array('db' => 'destinationName',      'dt' => 2),
    array('db' => 'projectStatus',     'dt' => 3), //Here is the status column
    array('db' => 'startDate',    'dt' => 4),
    array('db' => 'endDate',    'dt' => 5)
);

// Include SQL query processing class 
require 'ssp.class.php';

// Output data as json format 
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple($_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns)
);
```

My logic:

```
If (data) of projectStatus == 0 then display "Pending";
If (data) of projectStatus == 1 then display "Running";
If (data) of projectStatus == 2 then display "Completed";
```

Comment: Please hover over your "datatable" tag and read what it says.

Comment: As already suggested in your previous question have a table that defines your statuses and join that table in your query

Comment: @brombeer can just add an ifelse statement to displayy the string without creating a new table ?